# Which Marshal::Copy overload method used?

Tags: c++-cli, marshalling

Please consider the following C++/CLI code:

```
typedef unsigned __int8 uint8_t;
...
uint8_t          unmanaged_buf[MAVLINK_MAX_PACKET_LEN];
array<uint8_t>^  Buffer;
...
Marshal::Copy((IntPtr)unmanaged_buf, Buffer, 0, len);
```

Is the following the Marshal::Copy() method that is used?

`Marshal::Copy Method (IntPtr, array<Byte>, Int32, Int32)`

PS: The MSDN URL for the above method is at: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms146631.aspx

If it is, is it because `Byte` is the type that is closest to `unsigned __int8`?  Specifically, how does the Visual C++ compiler determine which method overload to use?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From [MSDN documentation about `__int8`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/29dh1w7z.aspx):

> The types `__int8`, `__int16`, and `__int32` are synonyms for the ANSI types that have the same size, and are useful for writing portable code that behaves identically across multiple platforms. *The `__int8` data type is synonymous with type `char`*, …

This doesn't say anything about the `unsigned` versions of the types, but I think it makes sense to assume that `unsigned __int8` is synonymous with `unsigned char`.

And from [.NET Framework Equivalents to C++ Native Types](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/0wf2yk2k.aspx):

> The following table shows the keywords for built-in Visual C++ types, which are aliases of predefined types in the System namespace.
>
> `unsigned char`: `System.Byte`

Putting this together, `unsigned __int8` is synonymous to an alias of `System.Byte`, which means it is the same as `System.Byte` in C++/CLI code.

Comment: +1 Thank you, especially for the second (equivalents) link.  Now it makes sense.

Comment: The first link is good as well, talks about promotion. Thanks.